# SQL: SELECT with UNION, ORDER BY and LIMIT

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by, union, limit

I'm getting Errors that ORDER by should come after UNION but i want these to queries ordered before combined to one and then limited to 10.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT time, x, y, z 
          FROM db 
         WHERE time >= now 
      ORDER by time, x
       UNION 
       SELECT time, x, y, z 
         FROM db 
        WHERE time < now 
     ORDER by time, x) 
LIMIT 10
```

I hope you understand, what I'm trying to do and can help me ;-)

Comment: It's for SQLITE: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: ORDER BY clause should come after UNION not before:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how it works, at least in MySQL (you didn't specify). The ORDER operation comes after the data is selected and all UNIONs, GROUP BYs, etc. have been performed.

See [SQL Server: ORDER BY in subquery with UNION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685563/sql-server-order-by-in-subquery-with-union) for a way around this.

Answer (score 35):

if you have a very complex query in SQLite but need to use UNION with ordering, then you can try

```
select * from (
    select * from b ORDER BY date asc
    )
UNION
select * from (
    select * from b ORDER BY name desc
    )
UNION
select * from (
    select * from b ORDER BY gender asc
    )
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I was trying to figure out what I needed besides the parentheses.

Comment: At least in SQL Server the outer selects need to be named i.e. `SELECT * FROM (...) AS x`.

Answer (score 7):

An order by will affect the ENTIRE union.

Anyway, it looks like you want the rows nearest to `now`.  You could try this:

```
SELECT   time, x, y, z 
FROM     db 
ORDER BY ABS(time - now) ASC
LIMIT    10
```

Answer (score 5):

In "standard" (for some definition of "standard") SQL;

```
select top 10 *
from (       select time,x,y,z from db where time > now
       union select time,x,y,z from db where time < now
     ) t
order by t.time
```

How to limit the number of rows in the result set may vary between SQL implementations.

Answer (score 2):

Any easy solution I applied was as follows :

```
SELECT 
 name,
 TO_DATE(date1, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI AM')
FROM TableX

UNION

SELECT
 name,
 TO_DATE(date2, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI AM')
FROM TableY

ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

This orders the results by the second (date) column.

If the date column is a string, you can apply the TO_DATE function as shown above, else it is not necessary.