# Android Sqlite - How to combine query using UNION ALL

Tags: android, sqlite

Im using Android Sqlite and want to execute two queries and combine the result. Everything works fine if the sorting is done for the combined result. But i want the sort order for each query separate and then combine the result.

This is what i found from [SQL: SELECT with UNION, ORDER BY and LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696947/sql-select-with-union-order-by-and-limit) and validated the query on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/98b6d/16 and works fine.

```
select * from (select * from supportContacts where (id=1) order by id asc)
UNION ALL
select * from (select * from supportContacts where (id!=1) order by RANDOM())
```

But how will i execute this query on android sqlite `ContentResolver.query()` or is there any way using  `rawQuery` .

Note: I'm using this query to get all the audio files from Media Provider for `MediaStore.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` , but i know the id of a audio file , so my first query will get only single audio and second query will get all the audio excluding the known audio id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use buildUnionQuery method from SQLiteQueryBuilder.

For more details, check the following link
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html#buildUnionQuery(java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String)