# SQLite: Need a SELECT query to filter a row and sort by a value passed in WHERE condition

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

TO make it understandable the following link in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_where) can be taken as an example.

Environment: Android, SQLite.

Problem: For instance

1. Select all the value from the column name "city", so it will return us an array.
2. But we need city "Cork" to be the index 0 of the array returned along with other city names sorted alphabetically.

This is the problem statement. please suggest if there is a solution at all or is it worth trying this way.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a question similar to this. The answer is use temporary table that will be selected with `order by`, then `select *` from there to union with other selection. The query I came up and tested is:

```
SELECT distinct City from Customers where city='Cork'
union all
select * from (select distinct city from customers where city<>'Cork' order by city asc)
```

[The question I refer to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685563/sql-server-order-by-in-subquery-with-union). Sadly, using `union` instead of `union all` didn't work.

Comment: Beautiful, it worked :) we also tried with UNION ALL but couldnt sort. Your solution worked well now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you do sort them in your application code ,not depend on SQL

Comment: ya we can, but we are seeking advice in doing it in query as such.

Comment: sql is slower than code. I did the same thing at my project: sqlite <-dbadapter api <- client use api.