# SQLite: UNION of n places ORDER BY size together with all the capitals?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by, union, union-all

I try to select from `ne_10m_populated_places` both the 15 biggest cities together with the 3~5 ones where `FEATURECLA='Admin-0 capital'` (the countries capitals). So for my area, I should get back ~18-20 places. I'am very beginner to SQL, and don't know where how basic operators chain up. I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM ne_10m_populated_places ORDER BY POP_MAX DESC LIMIT '15' 
OR WHERE FEATURECLA='Admin-0 capital'
```

The first line works, but it fails when I add it the second line. Help welcome !

---

**EDIT: no working answer yet.**

Answer (score 2):

The ordering of your statements is incorrect and you need to do a `UNION` if you want to add specific results.

In this example, we find the 15 most populated cities and then `UNION` specific cities that you've specified.

In the first query of the `UNION`, it is turned into a sub-select since `ORDER BY` will affect the entire `UNION` otherwise.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM ne_10m_populated_places
    ORDER BY POP_MAX DESC 
    LIMIT 15
)

UNION 

SELECT * 
FROM ne_10m_populated_places
WHERE FEATURECLA = 'Admin-0 capital'
```

Comment: @Doon - just turned it into a subselect. Should work now I think ... let me know if you find any issues with it since I don't have SQLite handy.

Comment: Beat me to it,  Was going to say subselect *should* work. (at least it parses now)

Comment: Wow, I was really far from It. I'am testing it.

Comment: This doesn't work for me unless the subquery is assigned a name. To be fair, I'm testing on SQL Server and not SQLite, which has very slightly different syntax (`SELECT TOP 15 *` instead of `LIMIT 15` at bottom)

Comment: @Hugolpz well it isn't that "basic" of a query (due to  order / limit on only part of the results)

Comment: @MariM yeah. TSQL would be a UnionAll and slightly different syntax,  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685563/sql-server-order-by-in-subquery-with-union

Comment: Indeed, I get only 12 results made of all the capitals (as expected) but far less populated places than expected. I try to find why.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ne_10m_populated_places ORDER BY POP_MAX DESC LIMIT 15` get back 15 biggest cities, white `SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM ne_10m_populated_places
    ORDER BY POP_MAX DESC 
    LIMIT 15
)` get back 4 cities.

Comment: Hahaha. Ok. I'am on the other page provided by Doon. Trouble is much harder than though !

Comment: @Hugolpz are you sure., seems to work as demonstrated here  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/a9734/2/0